# tcpdump not writing captured packets into a file

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I am running the following command in my server(`GNU/LINUX 2.6.27.5`):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w test.pcap
```

After stopping the packet capture manually it shows the number of packets captured & received by filter but the file `test.pcap` does not contain anything, means its size is `0`.

`tcpdump` version used is `tcpdump-3.9.8`

Comment: Are you sure there is traffic on `eth0`?

Comment: yes there is.Its also showing that some 200 or 300 packets captured but not writing to the file

Comment: Do you have sufficient free space on the disk? `df -h`

Comment: If you start it with `tcpdump -i eth0 -w -`, what happens? It should print to stdout instead of to file.

Comment: Maybe a file permission issue with the directory were you want to have that file written to? As suggested in a prior comment, I would try `tcpdump -i eth0` first and make sure you do get traffic on the console, and then move on to see why it is not writing to file.

Comment: Its printing to stdout.
I have logged in as root user.I am able to create normal files.
The permission is as follows:
-rw-r--r--  1 root root          0 2013-12-02 11:01 dump.pcap

Comment: Use -nn and -v options to get better idea ,if you are really getting any traffic there . For information about -nn and -v , please do "man"